# How to create folder within project

Tags: xcode

I want to have all my image files in a folder so that I can obtain all of them at the same time. I think the path should like this ...MyApp.app/image folder/1.png.
But when I drag them into xcode with folder references created, there is no folder. The path is always MyApp.app/1.png.

Also, I think I've dragged the files into the app several times. How to delete the files? It's not enough to just delete the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If they are not visible in project navigator, that means that you have no references to them and you can delete them directly in finder.
2. You are likely to have moved every image to a group rather than a folder. A group is just a convenience in Xcode project navigator. It has nothing to do with file hierarchy.

To keep them in a folder, right-click project navigator. Select new folder, drag your files to that folder. When they are visible in your project navigator, make sure that they are all linked to your project. I.e they are all check market with your project in the right pane.

It important to drag them to the folder and not just outside of it.

Comment: Right now I have MyApp.app/1.png and MyApp.app/image folder/1.png. I want to delete the files outside the folder. But they are in the app so I cannot delete them in finder. I don't have reference to them because I deleted the project and created a new one with the same name. I know they're there because I can find their paths in the new project. Do you know how to delete them?

Comment: It is considered great practice to post your solution of your problem as an answer and mark the answer as correct!

Comment: I know how to delete them in finder now. But every time I run the programme those files will be created automatically...

Comment: It feels like you are somehow creating the files programmatically if they keep coming back.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easiest way to do this in Xcode:

1)

Put all your images into a folder and then drag that folder into the list of files in your Xcode project.  That step looks like this:

[image: Drag folder of images into project]

2)

A sheet will drop down in Xcode and ask you how you want to add these files to your project.  It looks like this:

[image: Create Folder Reference]

There's a checkbox at the top there that says "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed).  You will check this if you want to copy your folder full of images into the same place where your source code is found in your Xcode project.

3)

When you're done adding, here is what your project should look like in Xcode.  Notice that the folder color is blue.  That means it's a folder reference.  This folder will be copied into your built application.

[image]

Comment: Oh yes, Thank you!
But I have to add the inDirectory otherwise it will give me the one outside the folder.
Do you know how to delete the files outside the folder? Those I dragged before.